# ¿como hago para sumar un numero a los resultados de un bucle?

Tags: javascript, html5, while, bucle-for

Hola tengo un bucle while decreciente al que le tengo que sumar 3 cada vez que muestre un numero par, pero no logro que me los sume ¿que estoy haciendo mal?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Descendiente Numeros Pares</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var num = 100;

while(num >= 50){

document.write("Numero: " + num + "<br>");
if(num%2==0){
num + 3;
 }
num--;
}


</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Primero creo que te lo estas planteando mal, si partes de 100, e iteras sobre este número, restándole 1 cada vez, pero le sumas 3 cada vez q sea par, estas generando un bucle infinito. Eso ya me dice que necesitas una segunda variable con la que operar.

Comment: no suma por que no estas asignando el valor en `num + 3;`. Tienes que asignar esa suma a la variable `num = num + 3;`

Answer (score 1):

Tu script podría ser:

```
var num = temp = 100;

while ( num >= 50 ) {

    

    //Si número par -> añado 3
    if (( temp % 2 ) == 0 ) {
        document.write( "Numero: " + temp + "<br>" );
        temp += 3;
    }

    temp--;
    num--;
}
```

Modificaciones:

> - Sólo muestra los números cuando son pares.
> - Fíjate en la forma de añadirle 3 a una variable.
> - Añadí otra variable, como te indique en los comentarios, para no generar un bucle infinito.